# comparing linked list , C++ , same order but can be different seize

Tags: c++, linked-list, compare

Let's say we are given the function definition

bool sameValsOrder(node *p , node *q)

We have to write a function to compare the 2 linked list if they have the same order it returns true else false
[77777] and [77] -> true

[1234567] and [1234555567] -> true

```
bool sameValsOrder (node *p , node *q)
{
     if ( q==NULL && p==NULL)
        return true;
     else if ((q=NULL && p != NULL)|| (p=NULL && q!= NULL))
         return false;
     else if ( q != NULL && p != NULL)
           while ( q != 0 && p != 0)
            {
                if (p->data != q->data)
                    {
                        return false;
                        break;
                    }
                else 
                    {
                  p= p-> next ;
                  q= q-> next;
                    } 
            }
             return true;
    }
```

The above code is my answer but I realized something. Do I need to add more if statement inside the while loop such that a link list of [77777] and [7] should return true since its the same order just less.

Comment: The `else` part of the nested `if` statement is missing braces.

Comment: I think all the current function does is tell you if the lists have the same first N data values, where N is the length of the shorter list.

Comment: @larsmans - the `if` part is too!  maybe it's python

Comment: @Brad yes my question is how do i add it so i can compare length of different values 

@larsman nice catch ill edit the main post again

Comment: @Brad: seems like the OP just edited the question without that showing up. The current code isn't even well-formed C++.

Comment: @larsmans the question tells me the write the function ... i just made the one above on the spot. The problem is i have no idea how to compare the array of different length...

Comment: @ricedragon: you should describe in some more detail what kind of comparison you're doing. Would `[1,2,3]` and `[1,3]` compare as equal?

Comment: @larsmans no but [1 2 2 1 ] and [1 2 1 ] would be equal , it can have repeated element but it have to be in the same order.

Comment: I would just write a removeConsecutiveDuplicates function, and after you remove duplicates run the resulting lists through your current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you have written you don't actually care about the values but you want to return true if the list is ordered?  It seems like you just need to go through each value in the list.  As long as the NEXT value is NOT LESS than the PREVIOUS value keep going through the list.  If you reach the end, then return true because the list is in order.  If, at any point you come across a value that is less than any previous value then just return false right there.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    node(){next = NULL;}
    int data;
    node * next;
};
class myList{
public:
    myList(){pRoot = NULL;}
    void add(int data);
    node * pRoot;
};
bool sameValsOrder (node *p , node *q)
{
     if ( q==NULL && p==NULL) // If both lists are empty
        return true;
     else if ((q==NULL && p != NULL)|| (p==NULL && q!= NULL)) // One list is empty and the other is not
         return false;
     else if ( q != NULL && p != NULL) //Both lists contain values we must check
     {      
         int temp; //I am going to assume a singly linked list (no access to previous value), need this to hold previous value
         temp = p->data; 
         while (p->next != NULL) //The list still contains elements
         {
            if (p->next->data < temp) //The value in the current node is LESS than our temp, then list is out of order so return false
                return false;
            else { //Otherwise move to the next node
                temp = p->data;
                p = p->next;
            }
         }
         temp = q->data; //Reset temp for q
         //Do the same thing for q
         while (q->next != NULL) //The list still contains elements
         {
            if (q->next->data < temp) //The value in the current node is LESS than our temp, then list is out of order so return false
                return false;
            else { //Otherwise move to the next node
                temp = q->data;
                q = q->next;
            }
         }
     }
     return true; //If we are this are then both lists should be ordered
}
int main()
{
    myList * p = new myList();
    myList * q = new myList();
    p->add(7);
    p->add(6);
    p->add(5);
    p->add(4);
    p->add(3);
    p->add(2);
    p->add(1);

    q->add(7);
    q->add(6);
    q->add(5);
    q->add(5);
    q->add(5);
    q->add(5);
    q->add(4);
    q->add(3);
    q->add(2);
    q->add(1);
    cout << sameValsOrder (p->pRoot, q->pRoot) << endl;
    return 0;
}
void myList::add(int data)
{
    node * nodeToAdd = new node();
    nodeToAdd->data = data;
    if(pRoot == NULL) //List is empty
    {
        pRoot = nodeToAdd;
        pRoot->next = NULL;
    }
    else //List not empty insert new node at beginning
    {
        nodeToAdd->next = pRoot;
        pRoot = nodeToAdd;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pete that seems about right but the next value have to be equal to the previous value , not less than or more than. eg.
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 2 2] and  [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 4 2 2 ]  is ok!

Comment: @ricedragon I'll leave the code up but apparently I dont understand how either of those are in any kind of order.  The only way I can see to do what you want to do is to check through the list every time up until your current position to see if the current position already exists?

Comment: @Pete that seems to work so I need 3 while loop to check it. Thats why i am missing and it that seems okey ill trace it again slowly. Thank you for replying

Comment: @ricedragon  No problem.  I wrote the code to work for the two examples you gave.  In your original post you gave [1234567] and [1234555567] -> true.  My function should return true given those values.  However, given the values you have commented on here, requires a bit more work.

Comment: @Pete I dont get the why there is 2 temp using the same name. shouldn't be 
{
temp = p->data
while (q->next != NULL)
 if (q->data != temp)
 return false
 else
 q->next
}
blah .. the code tag doesnt work there and its just the order so [1 1 1 2 ] is equal to [1 2]. and shouldn't  the temp have a different name like temp 1 and temp 2 so it doesn't overwrite each other? and my teacher says i dont get the question.. i posted here and half of the people dont get it either .... sigh....

Comment: @ricedragon No, I just reused the same variable.  I put a comment in there where I "reset" it.  Also, in my code, I didn't reassign temp. every time through the loop.  I'm sure the code isnt perfect but the logic is there.  It's ok if temp is overwritten.  We need temp to go through the first list (p).  When we are done with p, we can do whatever we want with temp.  So I reuse it for (q).  That's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Pete oh ... ill use temp1 and temp2 when i "write the code" out for exam just for safety ... apparently my teacher is very picky... i got my code right for the 2 midterm let say a question is out of 8 , i make a few mistake so -2 > that okey  -1 for syntax error < okey i can live with that  -3 for bad programming style + not efficient ( <= that piss me off .. its not like im a CPU with a compiler build it that counts efficiently calculator build  in a 1 hour exam!)

Comment: @ricedragon There is a complete working program you can play around with.  I've added your sample data from your original post.  If you need something different, just change it around.  Now you can trace it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(q!=NULL || p!=NULL)
{    
    if(q->data==p->data)    
    { 
        p=p->next;
        break;
    }
    else(q->data <  p->data)
    q=q->next;
}
```

Basically you should move forward in the first linked list only when the values don't match other wise traverse the second list till it matches.

Comment: @ garima can you fix the code? its kind of hard to read ... thank you

Comment: you should first check the length of both the linked lists and then traverse the bigger one say Q... compare it with the values of the other list say P.. if the value in Q is less.. move next. else P->next..

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ( q != 0 && p != 0)
        {
            if (p->data != q->data)
                    return false;
                    break;
            else 
              p= p-> next ;
              q= q-> next;
        }
```

this is wrong you are returning false when it is not same but as the size of p and q can be different 
[1112]  [12] will return false which it shouldnt

Answer (score 0):

The OP has indicated in comments that he wants to consider 'runs' of nodes with the same data as being matched even if those runs have a difference length in the 2 lists.  That simplifies to when `(q->data == p->data)` then skip nodes that comprise a run.

Here's some pseudocode; a C implementation is really not any more complex (though it might be several more lines):

```
bool sameValsOrder (node *p , node *q)
{
    while not at the end of either list, and the current nodes are the same {

        skip run in q, taking care to deal with the NULL at the end of the list

        skip run in p, taking care to deal with the NULL at the end of the list
    }

    if we've reached the end of both lists, they are equivalent
}
```

C Implementation:

```
bool sameValsOrder (node *p , node *q)
{
    while (q && p && (q->data == p->data)) {
        /* find next different node in each list (ie., skip runs) */

        int tmp = q->data;  /* or whatever type `data` is */

        while (q && (q->data == tmp)) {
            q = q->next;
        }

        while (p && (p->data == tmp)) {
            p = p->next;
        }
    }

    /*
     * we've either reached the end of one or both lists, 
     *  or have found a `data` difference
     */

    if (p == q) {
        /* should happen only when `q` and `p` are NULL */
        assert(q == NULL);
        assert(p == NULL);

        /* we've reached the end of both lists, so they're 'equivalent' */

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```